# SSIS - Oracle Connector missing in VS2019

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I need to convert our existing 2017 SSIS packages to 2019. Many of these connect to Oracle 19c dbs. In VS2017 we used the Attunity connector successfully.

I currently have VS2017 and VS2019 installed on my development machine to allow me to work through the conversion.

I have installed VS2019 with the required extensions and have 32 & 64bit Oracle drivers installed, but I do not have Oracle source and destinations in my SSIS toolbox. Neither do I have an Oracle connection option in my Connection Manager. I can successfully create connections to Oracle via ODBC and OLEDB but both of these options are problematic for our existing solutions.

I manually installed the MS Oracle connector (32 &64 bit) even though I understand that it should come with the VS2019 SSIS extension out of the box, but I'm still not seeing the connector in VS2019 as described in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

TIA

Comment: How did you install 32 & 64bit Oracle drivers?

Comment: Downloaded the latest version of the instant client basic plus odbc (32 & 64). Extracted into oracle directory, ran the odbc installer, added the location to the PATH environment variable and added the relevant location in to the TNS_NAMES environment variable. Added the relevant details to the registry for both bit types.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to uninstall SQL Server Integration Services Projects v 4.2 and install 3.16 instead.
4.2 doesn't support the Oracle connector.
Make sure you do a reboot after switching.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview